# To keep the btn:focus styling

Tags: css

I am trying to keep the btn:focus styling after clicking away. How can I do it?

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="item1" class="hello btn btn-default"> item1 </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="item2" class="hello btn btn-default"> item2 </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="item3" class="hello btn btn-default"> item3 </a>

.btn:hover,  
.btn:focus {
   background: #00f;
   border-color: #00f; }
```

Comment: you will need javascript to add a class when clicked

Comment: So there is not a simple way to keep the style with css. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(".btn").addClass("custom-focus");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.custom-focus {
   background: #00f;
   border-color: #00f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**By using Javascript** `onclick="addFocus(this)` and add class to selector with wanted style as below:

```js
function addFocus(elem){
 elem.className += " focus";
}
```

```css
.btn:hover,  
.focus {
   background: #00f;
   border-color: #00f; 
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" id="item1" class="hello btn btn-default" onclick="addFocus(this)"> item1 </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="item2" class="hello btn btn-default" onclick="addFocus(this)"> item2 </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="item3" class="hello btn btn-default" onclick="addFocus(this)"> item3 </a>
```

Comment: that what you mean?